# Shrinking a hypergraph to a graph with identical chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory, graph-colorings, hypergraph

Let $H=(V,E)$ be a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph). A *coloring* is a map $c:V\to \kappa$ where $\kappa\neq \emptyset$ is a cardinal, and the restriction $c\restriction_e:e\to \kappa$ is non-constant for every $e\in E$ with $|e|>1$. The *chromatic number* of H is the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such that there is a coloring $c:V\to\kappa$.

If $S\subseteq V$, we let $\text{Gr}_H(S) = (S, E|_S)$ be the graph on $S$ having the edge set  $$E|_S = \{\{s,t\}: s\neq t\in S \land (\exists e\in E(H)(s,t\in e))\}.$$

**Question.** If $H=(V,E)$ is a hypergraph such that $E\neq \emptyset$ and $|e|>1$ for all $e\in E$, is there $S\subseteq V$ with the following properties?

1. $|S\cap e|\leq 2$ for all $e\in E$, and
2. $\chi(\text{Gr}_H(S)) = \chi(H)$.

Comment: Did you really mean to require that $|S\cap e|\le2$ for all $e\in E$? So if $H=(V,E)$ is a complete $3$-uniform hypergraph, $E=[V]^3$, you want $|S|\le2$?

Comment: Let $H=(V,E)$ where $|V|\ge5$ and $E=[V]^3$. Plainly $\chi(H)=\left\lceil\frac{|V|}2\right\rceil\ge3$. If $S\subseteq V$ and $|S\cap e|\le2$ for all $e\in E$ then $|S|\le2$ and $\chi(\operatorname{Gr}_H(S))\le2\lt\chi(H)$. Are you sure you stated the question correctly?

Comment: Thanks @bof - I have to think more about my formulation, but you can post this as an answer so we can close this thread as long as I don't have a better formulation

Comment: Maybe you could just delete this question, at least for now, and undelete it later if you come up with a corrected formulation?